# How make JSON-files part of project in VisualStudio 2012

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2012

How make JSON-files part of project in VisualStudio 2012? How access to the file? How to set them copy automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How make JSON-files part of project in Visual Studio 2012

Right-click the project and select `"Add files..."` option (you can reference *any* inside a project).

> How access to the file?

You would need to elaborate a bit more on this one...access *when* exactly? During runtime/design time?

> How to set them copy automatically

Right-click the file once added to the project and set the `Copy to Output Dir` option to `true`.

Comment: @Zverit you can open the JSON file directly in VS.

Comment: Add new files, I can't see any .json format in Vs2012

Comment: @King_Fisher just opt for "All files" if it's not part of the file types.

Answer (score 3):

1. place json file in solution folder in windows
2. Press Show all files.
3. Right click and press include in project.
4. Right-click the file added to the project --> set the Copy to Output Dir option to true

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on Project/Folder where you want to add the JSON file
2. Hover on `Add`
3. Click `New Item`

or use the Shortcut for `New Item`( Step 1-3 ) which is `Ctrl+Shift+A`

4. Select `JSON File`
5. Set the Filename then click `Add` button